# selenim web driver python repet code ultimate

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

how repeat code again again again this every work 
I want the code below to always work and it should be repeated, and again this function should be repeated and not removed from the program.

```
def ref(self):
    driver = self.driver
    nextB2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//section/span/button/span[@aria-label='Like']""")
    nextB2.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    nextB3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//section/span/button/span[@aria-label='Like']""")
    nextB3.click()
    time.sleep(6)
    nextB4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//section/span/button/span[@aria-label='Like']""")
    nextB4.click()
    time.sleep(7)
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.switch_to_frame('ref')
    driver.refresh('ref')
```

Comment: which part of code you want to execute repeatedly or is it entire function which has to repeated

Comment: all part code repeated

Comment: Just add a while loop or for loop and call the function how much time ever you want

Comment: I do not know  you can loop call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use for loop with range to stop at perticular count like

```
for i in range(10):  #10 times
  ref() #function call
```

if you want it to run for ever

```
while True: #loop that never stops
  ref()
```

you can use break and continue for conditional breaks

```
 while True:
  if foo == foo:
    break #break or stop the while oop
  elif foo == bar:
    continue #skip current iteration and continue execution
  else:
    ref()
```

Comment: wrong to code 
 error code  how ad while True:
ref()

Comment: how to add                              while True:
  if foo == foo:
    break #break or stop the while oop
  elif foo == bar:
    continue #skip current iteration and continue execution
  else:
    ref()

Comment: who is foo and bar